# Using Applescript to selectively activate one instance of an app with two running instances

Tags: applescript

I am running two instances of iTerm at once on my computer (OS X 10.9). I copied the iTerm bundle and made the following changes:

- rename bundle **iTerm copy.app** > **scratchpad.app**
- rename **scratchpad.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm** > **scratchpad**
- in `Info.plist`, set **CFBundleName** > **scratchpad**
- in `Info.plist`, set **CFBundleIdentifier** > **com.seanmackesey.scratchpad**
- in `Info.plist`, set **CFBundleExecutable** > **scratchpad**

I am able to run the two instances successfully-- in the dock and menu bar, the second instance is labeled "scratchpad", as desired. However, when I execute the applescript:

```
tell application "iTerm" to activate
```

this will cause my scratchpad to activate. How can I avoid this, so that this line activates only my original iTerm instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try activating by application [bundle] *ID*:

```applescript
tell application id "net.sourceforge.iTerm" to activate
```

As for why what you're seeing happens:
There are two additional properties you may have to change:

- `CFBundleDisplayName`
- `CFDisplayName`

To get an application's [bundle] ID, by the way, simply run (in Terminal), for instance:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm" to id'
```

Answer (score 1):

I like what mklement has posted about using the application id. An alternative method is using system events and processes. Processes have properties that can help you identify a particular running process. For example maybe by using the "displayed name" property or "name" or "short name" or "title" or etc. So you can look at the properties and pick out something unique about it and identify it. Once you have the particular process you can bring it to the front like this. Notice I'm using the "displayed name" property to identify Safari in this example.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theProcess to first application process whose displayed name is "Safari"
    set frontmost of theProcess to true
end tell
```